# Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::fetch() in C:\wamp\www\FINAL login\memberpage.php on line 24

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Am really confused about this error
i have done everything to solve this error but i cant do anything
can someone help me

am trying to display all value store in SQL database in php

```
    <?php
require('includes/config.php');
//if not logged in redirect to login page
if (!$user->is_logged_in()) {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
//define page title
$title = 'Members Page';
//include header template
require('layout/header.php');
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">
            <h2>Member only page - Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h2>
            <p><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></p>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM password");
    $result->execute();

    while ($row = $db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
    $title = $row['email'];
    $body = $row['pass'];
    }
    echo "<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Usernamw</th>
    <th>Password</th> 
      </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>" . $title . "</td>
    <td>" . $body . "</td> 
  </tr>
  </table>" ?>
</div>
<?php
//include header template
require('layout/footer.php');
?>
```

this is were i get error

```
    while ($row = $db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

Comment: using the wrong variable.

Comment: yes declared in seperate file

Comment: Yes, Jay's answer, which is what I meant ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up your variables/objects:

```
while ($row = $db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

should be

```
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

You have to fetch your result, not your connection.

**EDIT**: To get all of your rows to echo, you have to include them in the `while` loop:

```
echo "<table>
<tr>
    <th>Usernamw</th>
    <th>Password</th> 
</tr>";

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $title = $row['email'];
    $body = $row['pass'];
    echo "<tr><td>" . $title . "</td><td>" . $body . "</td></tr>";
}

 echo "</table>";
```

Comment: its displaying only one row i need to display all rows

Comment: You have to perform the echoing of your HTML inside the while loop, not outside @sanojlawrence

Comment: can you please explain how do i do that

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `fetch` on `$result` `$result->fetch()`.

Comment: i get this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE) in C:\wamp\www\FINAL login\memberpage.php on line 25`

Comment: Did you wrote `$result->execute(); while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`?

Comment: i need to display all rows

Answer (score -2):

`prepare()` is a method of a PDO object, while `fetch()` is a PDOStatement method. `$result->fetch` should work.